# Why can't an if be used as statement to another if on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax-error

An `ìf` works fine as single line statement, like this:

```
if True: print('OK')
```

However, if that is given as statement to another single line `if`, it generates a syntax error, as for:

```
if True: if True: print('Breaks with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"')
```

Why is this construction a syntax error?

Comment: technically you could rewrite the second line, as `if True and True:` if you really wanted to

Comment: See [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html). Exactly that example. Reason: "it wouldn’t be clear to which if clause a following else clause would belong".

Comment: Sure, but the case was triggered by a code construction where it would be more obvious to use the `if cond1: if cond2: statement`, which is why I hit this issue.

Comment: I generally consider single-line ifs to be bad style anyway, and this serves as a perfect example of why.  If your code has the habit of jamming everything onto one line you'll inevitably hit situations where the thing that feels "obvious" doesn't work and doing it the right (syntactically valid) way will feel awkward because it doesn't match the rest of your code.

Comment: I think there are specific cases where single line `if` makes sense, for example in some cases of error handling, e.g. `if not match: sys.exit("ERROR: Match was expected")`.

Answer (score 1):

As jarmod pointed, the reference by `else` clause would not be clear in:

```
if cond_1: if cond_2: print('if part')
else: print('else part, would that be for cond_1 or cond_2 ?')
```